# google map APIで複数の住所をマーカー表示したい

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

日本語住所から、google map APIを用いて、複数のマーカーを地図上に表示させるコードを作っています。

複数の住所は、for文を用いてGeocode処理しています。
また、Geocodeの返り値は非同期処理とのことで、callback関数を使って、すべて住所の緯度経度を取得してから地図を完成させるようにコーディングしています。

実際に当コードを実行してみると、画面上には何の表示もされず（地図は出てこず真っ白）、chromeのデベロッパーツールのconsole上でも何のエラーも表示されません。

コード中にalertを入れて確認してみると、住所の緯度経度自体はきちんと取得できています。
しかし、地図の中心点を指定する変数の部分はundefinedとなっていました。

いろいろ試行錯誤したのですが、どこが間違っているのか、煮詰まって先に進めません。
（callback関数の使い方を含め、いろいろ違っているかと思います。）
何がおかしいのか、ご指摘いただけますでしょうか。

```
<script>
function initMap() {

    var addresses = [
        '東京都千代田区永田町1丁目7-1',
        '東京都千代田区霞が関2丁目1番1号',
        '東京都千代田区霞が関1-1-1',
        '東京都千代田区霞が関2-1-3'
    ];

    var latlng = []; //緯度経度の値をセット
    var marker = []; //マーカーの位置情報をセット
    var myLatLng; //地図の中心点をセット用
    var geocoder;
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'));//地図を作成する

    geo(aftergeo);

    function geo(callback){
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            geocoder.geocode({'address': addresses[i]}, 
                function(results, status) { // 結果
                    if (status ===     google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { // ステータスがOKの場合
                        latlng[i]=results    [0].geometry.location;// マーカーを立てる位置をセット
                        marker[i] = new     google.maps.Marker({
                            position: results    [0].geometry.location, // マーカーを立てる位置を指定
                            map: map // マーカーを立てる地図を指定
                        });
                    } else { // 失敗した場合
                    }//if文の終了。ifは文なので;はいらない
                }//function(results, status)の終了
            );//geocoder.geocodeの終了
        }//for文の終了
        callback();//全て取得できたらaftergeo実行
    }//function geo終了

    function aftergeo(){
        myLatLng = latlng[0];//最初の住所を地図の中心点に設定
        var opt = {
            center: myLatLng, // 地図の中心を指定
            zoom: 16 // 地図のズームを指定
        };//地図作成のオプションのうちcenterとzoomは必須
        map.setOptions(opt);//オプションをmapにセット
    }//function aftergeo終了

};//function initMap終了

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

非同期処理なので、「geocoder.geocode」の「function(results, status) { // 結果」はfor文が**すべて終わってから**呼び出されます。
以下の様にforの変数「i」をfunctionの名前空間で保存するようにして、cRef変数でアドレスがすべてGeocode処理されたのを確認して callback を呼び出すようにすると動作します。

```
<script>
function initMap() {

    var addresses = [
        '東京都千代田区永田町1丁目7-1',
        '東京都千代田区霞が関2丁目1番1号',
        '東京都千代田区霞が関1-1-1',
        '東京都千代田区霞が関2-1-3'
    ];

    var latlng = []; //緯度経度の値をセット
    var marker = []; //マーカーの位置情報をセット
    var myLatLng; //地図の中心点をセット用
    var geocoder;
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'));//地図を作成する

    geo(aftergeo);

    function geo(callback){
        var cRef = addresses.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
            (function (i) { 
                geocoder.geocode({'address': addresses[i]}, 
                    function(results, status) { // 結果
                        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { // ステータスがOKの場合
                            latlng[i]=results[0].geometry.location;// マーカーを立てる位置をセット
                            marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: results[0].geometry.location, // マーカーを立てる位置を指定
                                map: map // マーカーを立てる地図を指定
                            });
                        } else { // 失敗した場合
                        }//if文の終了。ifは文なので;はいらない
                        if (--cRef <= 0) {
                            callback();//全て取得できたらaftergeo実行
                        }
                    }//function(results, status)の終了
                );//geocoder.geocodeの終了
            }) (i);
        }//for文の終了
    }//function geo終了

    function aftergeo(){
        myLatLng = latlng[0];//最初の住所を地図の中心点に設定
        var opt = {
            center: myLatLng, // 地図の中心を指定
            zoom: 16 // 地図のズームを指定
        };//地図作成のオプションのうちcenterとzoomは必須
        map.setOptions(opt);//オプションをmapにセット
    }//function aftergeo終了

};//function initMap終了

</script>
```

Comment: ご回答感謝します！
早速試してみます。
取り急ぎ御礼まで。

Comment: 正常表示できました！
geocodeの『非同期処理』について、他のjavascriptとの（動作の）兼ね合いをきちんと理解していなかったようです。
『function(results, status) { // 結果』の部分が非同期であって、for文全体の値が後で戻ってくるというわけではなかったのですね。
ありがとうございました。
助かりました。

Comment: ＠Washida さん、回答の承認ができるのでご確認ください。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer